# SharePoint 2013 Search Configuration Error with: $clone.Activate()

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search

I'm trying to re-build search on local SharePoint 2013 farm.
I'm getting an error on the last step: $clone.Activate().

## Error:

Exception calling "Activate" with "0" argument(s): "Topology activationfailed. Service call AddAdminNode failed with message 'AdminComponent1 is already configured Parameter name: name'"

I think if I could delete "AdminComponent1" configuration maybe Icould re-run?

I'm logged in as the Farm Account while performing this.
Listing my transcript text to show the commands I ran.

Any tips appreciated.

Kevin

============================================

```
$saAppPoolName = "SharePoint_SearchApp"  
$searchServerName = (Get-ChildItem env:computername).value  
$serviceAppName = "Search Service Application"  
$searchDBName = "SearchService_DB"  

# Grab the Appplication Pool for Service Application Endpoint
$saAppPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool $saAppPoolName  

# Start Search Service Instances
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance $searchServerName  
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance $searchServerName

# Create the Search Service Application and Proxy  
$searchServiceApp = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name $serviceAppName -ApplicationPool $saAppPoolName -DatabaseName $searchDBName  

$searchProxy = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -Name "$serviceAppName Proxy" -SearchApplication $searchServiceApp  

# Clone the default Topology (which is empty) and create a new one and then activate it  
$clone = $searchServiceApp.ActiveTopology.Clone()  

$searchServiceInstance = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance  

New-SPEnterpriseSearchAdminComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance  

New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance  

New-SPEnterpriseSearchAnalyticsProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance  

New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance  

New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance  

New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $searchServiceInstance
```

## Error is this line:

`$clone.Activate()`

## Error Message:

```
Exception calling "Activate" with "0" argument(s): "Topology activationfailed. Service call AddAdminNode failed with message 'AdminComponent1 is already configured Parameter name: name'"
At line:1 char:1
+ $clone.Activate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SearchTopologyActivationException
```

Comment: You say you are "rebuilding" your SSA. If you already have one running you don't need the New-SPESSA....You just need to clone it and change the topology. I suspect that your attempt to duplicate the Admin Component on the same hardware is the root of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to delete search and recreate it from Central Admin.  This allowed me to get search working.  I have not tried running my power shell scripts again.